# Can I use an array to compare multiple criteria using the like operator?

Tags: excel, vba

Can I use `Array` to compare multiple criteria using `Like` statement

Example:

```
LCase(Cells(lig, 2)) Like Array("object**", "**cash**", "lobby**")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use following syntax with Or

```
(LCase(Cells(lig, 2)) Like "object**") Or (LCase(Cells(lig, 2)) Like "**cash**") Or (LCase(Cells(lig, 2)) Like "lobby**")
```

And so on

Comment: While you *can* do it, you *won't want* to do that, because repetitive code is bad code and results in errors. It is harder to maintain, harder to read and therefore it is a bad practice. Actuall this is no valid Syntax `… Like ""**cash**"") …` and should even not compile.

Comment: Actually, there interesting variants to use Join array function, but there are Evaluate circumstances I stacked

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. You must loop through the array and check each item of the array individually.

```
Dim Criteria() As Variant
Criteria = Array("object**", "**cash**", "lobby**")

Dim Criterion As Variant
For Each Criterion In Criteria
    If LCase(Cells(lig, 2)) Like Criterion Then 
        '...
    End If 
Next Criterion
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to loop through the array in order to compare multiple values.

For a one-dimensional array, try the following

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Array("object*", "*cash*", "lobby*")
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If LCase(Cells(lig, 2)) Like arr(i) Then
        'Do something
    End If
Next i
```

Furthermore, you are using `Cells` without specifying a workbook/worksheet. In this case, VBA always refers to the active wb & ws, which may not be as you wish.